# NSCFData gunzippedData crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, payu

I am integrating PayU in my swift 2 based project by using sample code source from link: https://github.com/payu-intrepos/iOS-SDK/releases/tag/v3.3

The app crashes with the following log in the console, when the payu webview code from the class PayUUIPaymentUIWebViewController is executed:

> webViewDidStartLoad URL-----> 2016-01-07 19:07:59.788
>   MyTestApp[14764:2080307] -[__NSCFData gunzippedData]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7f80395de440 2016-01-07 19:07:59.809
>   MyTestApp[14764:2080307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData gunzippedData]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f80395de440'

It is an unhandled exception. Does anyone know what this means? What could be the cause of it?

Comment: They cover this in their issue tracker: https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Documentations/issues/3

Comment: Thanks Rob Napier for pointing out the link to the solution. As per the link, I had forgottent to added -Objc in Other Linker Flags in Project Build Settings, as my initial implementation was using swift and the payU code was in Objective-C. This solution works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Xcode project add "-Objc" in Other Linker Flags in Project Build Settings.